# HTML5/Javascript: Subtracting from Value

Tags: javascript, html

I wish I was writing this for something other than how to subtract from a value, but I'm not. I have a game set up, where asteroids come at the player, who you can move around. If an asteroid hits the player, it's supposed to subtract a random amount (within range) from the score. Actually, it somehow adds to the score instead. Below is my code:

```
for(var i=0; i<asteroids.length; i++){
    if(player.x<asteroids[i].x+asteroids[i].radius){
        if(player.x>asteroids[i].x-asteroids[i].radius){
            if(player.y<asteroids[i].y+asteroids[i].radius){
                if(player.y>asteroids[i].y-asteroids[i].radius){
                    player.lives-=Math.floor(Math.random()*(900000-600000)-600000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The if statements check if the player is overlapping an asteroid. I tried writing 'player.lives -= whatever' and 'player.lives = player.lives - whatever', and neither method works, and it just added to the score.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? thanks.

Comment: trace the value of player.lives . My best guess is that it has a negative value and hence when you do the subtraction, it adds up!

Comment: `Math.random()*(900000-600000)-600000` will equal a negative number.

Comment: Also instead of using four `if` conditions , try 
`if(player.x<asteroids[i].x+asteroids[i].radius && player.x>asteroids[i].x-asteroids[i].radius && player.y<asteroids[i].y+asteroids[i].radius && player.y>asteroids[i].y-asteroids[i].radius)`

Comment: Or, `Math.abs(asteroids[i].x - player.x) < asteroids[i].radius && Math.abs(asteroids[i].y - player.y) < asteroids[i].radius)`.  Seems to me that declares the intent a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `Math.random()*(900000-600000)-600000` will equal a negative number. Here's why:

```
Math.random() >>> a random value between 0 and 1

900000-600000 >>> a constant = 300000

Math.random() * 300000 >>> a random value between 0 and 300000

Math.random() * 300000 - 600000 >>> a random value between -600000 and -300000
```

The solution is to change

```
player.lives-=Math.floor(Math.random()*(900000-600000)-600000);
```

to

```
player.lives+=Math.floor(Math.random()*(900000-600000)-600000);
```

or just

```
player.lives-=Math.floor(Math.random()*300000+300000);
```

Answer (score -1):

as the comments say:

- you were better doing, if you use a collision system instead of 4 monster-if-conditions
- `Math.random()*(900000-600000)-600000` is a negative number.

Comment: summing up comments isn't really an answer

Comment: wow, now I feel stupid! thanks for letting me know that it was negative. it's all fixed now, seeing as I multiplied it by *1 :)

Comment: @JeremyDarrach : Glad you could fix it :)